# Move all zeroes to the end of an array with the order of the elements preserved

Tags: java, arrays, swap

Can anyone tell me what have I done wrong in this code ?

In this approach, I traverse the array and, as soon as I find a 0 element, I traverse to the right of the 0, and swap it with the 1st non-0 element found.

```
class Solution {
    public void moveZeroes(int[] nums) {
       for (int i = 0; i < nums.length;i++) {
           if (nums[i]==0) {
               for(int j = i+1; j < nums.length;j++) {
                   if(nums[j]!=0) {
                       int temp = nums[i];
                       nums[i]=nums[j];
                       nums[j]=temp;
                   }
               }
           }
       } 
       
    }
}
```

For this following input,
[0,1,0,3,12]

The expected output is
[1,3,12,0,0]

But I am getting
[12,3,1,0,0]

Comment: You don't start at the end of the array looking for non-zeroes to swap with

Comment: By the way, your problem specification doesn't say anything about the order of the non-zero elements. Both the expected and the actual output match the requirement you defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is no requirement with regard to the ordering, just to keep the original sequence with shifted zeros only you forgot to break the cycle once you have done a shift, so the corresponding method should look like the following:

```
class Solution {
    public void moveZeroes(int[] nums) {
       for (int i = 0; i < nums.length;i++) {
           if (nums[i]==0) {
               for(int j = i+1; j < nums.length;j++) {
                   if(nums[j]!=0) {
                       int temp = nums[i];
                       nums[i]=nums[j];
                       nums[j]=temp;
                       break;
                   }
               }
           }
       } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to point out, there's no need to use swapping to do this, since one of the elements is known to be zero. You also don't need to have an inner loop to search for the next non-zero element to shift down:

```
// A "source" and "destination" pointer: you will read elements 
// from the "source", write them to the "destination".
for (int src = 0, dst = 0; src < nums.length; ++src) {
  if (nums[src] != 0) {
    nums[dst++] = nums[src];
    nums[src] = 0;
  }
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/hXL13l)

Think of it this way: when you find a non-zero element, you want to shift it to be next to the previous non-zero element you shifted.

If you know where you shifted the current non-zero element to (`dst`), you will shift the next non-zero element to `dst+1`. Just keep incrementing `dst` every time you shift an element, and it then points to the next place to shift to.

Comment: Yea, the efficiency(algorithm complexity) of the method worth mentioning for sure, but the question was about mistake within the code provided.

Comment: @MaksymKosenko I do mention this is "just pointing something out".

Answer (score 0):

```
class PushZero
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int arr[] = {1, 9, 8, 4, 0, 0, 2, 7, 0, 6, 0, 9};
        int n = arr.length;
        pushZerosToEnd(arr, n);
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
    }
    static void pushZerosToEnd(int arr[], int n)
    {
        int count = 0;  
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (arr[i] != 0)
            arr[count++] = arr[i];
        while (count < n)
            arr[count++] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code takes the same approach as mine - great minds etc - but I would suggest you put in some effort to explain what is going on in your code, as well as formatting it to be readable.